# How to make manager comments mandatory in SOA Workflow

Tags: soa, composite, oid, oim, oam

UseCase : I want to make the manager comments mandatory in soa /oim workflow before accepting rejecting any request from user .

Please suggest .

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the workflow in the Jdevloper.
2. Double click on [YourTaskName]Task.task -> In General-> Outcomes ->
3. click search button
4. Click the outcome requiring comments and check "REJECT" and "ACCEPT" check box
5. Redeploy the composite on to soa server.